# Cycling the day after squatting

Tags: squats, bicycling, rest

Currently I am doing a program similar too 5x5 stronglift, which contains squats.

The squats are getting heavier each week and are making my muscles sore(in a good way).

Every week day i cycle to work for about 20 minutes and that can get pretty nasty when I did squat the day or even 2 days before. I am noticing the muscle soreness sticks around way longer in my legs than in my chest or back.

Are my legs not getting enough rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one word, **yes.** If you receive StrongLift's periodic emails, Mehdi, the program's creator usually advises that cardio or leg exercises should be reduced on resting days because that'll prevent the legs from obtaining their required rests, especially as the weights increase.

So, if you're cycling 40 mins daily, your legs will have a harder time recovering as the weights increase.

While it would be unrealistic to tell you not to bike to work or to stop your current program, you might want to research more on ways to increase the resting period given to your legs.